# Identify records NOT in another dataframe

Tags: pandas, merge

I have one dataframe like this:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame([['a','z',0],['a','y',20],['b','z',1]],columns=['id1','id2','number'])
data2 = pd.DataFrame([['a','y',1],['a','y',1],['b','z',0]],columns=['id1','id2','number'])
```

I want to return the records that are in data1 and not data2 (as joined by id1 and id2).

In this case, I would just want it to return one record ['a','z',0] since both ['a','y'] and ['b','z'] do exist in data2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is an alternative way. If we set both columns as index we can use `.isin` method to filter out what's needed:

```
data1.set_index(['id1', 'id2'], inplace=True)
data2.set_index(['id1', 'id2'], inplace=True)
data1[~data1.index.isin(data2.index)].reset_index()
```

Yields:

```
  id1 id2  number
0   a   z       0
```

Regardless of what you have in the `number`.

Comment: These both worked but this seems a bit more elegant to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A bit tricky this one, normally when we want to filter out rows using multiple conditions we would do something like:

```
In [39]:
data1[(data1.id1 != data2.id1) & (data1.id2 != data2.id2)]
Out[39]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id1, id2, number]
Index: []
```

but this yields no rows because the condition is not satisfied because at least one of the id values is matched.

So what we really want is to use both columns as an id column and then filter out the rows that are only in data1.

To achieve this we can perform a left merge first:

```
In [33]:
merged = data1.merge(data2, on=['id1', 'id2'], how='left')
merged
Out[33]:
  id1 id2  number_x  number_y
0   a   z         0       NaN
1   a   y        20         1
2   a   y        20         1
3   b   z         1         0
```

Now we want just the rows where the right hand side is null as this indicates that the composite index value does not exist:

```
In [36]:

merged_null = merged[merged.number_y.isnull()]
merged_null

Out[36]:
  id1 id2  number_x  number_y
0   a   z         0       NaN
```

Now we can use this to select our rows from the original dataframe using `isin` to select those id values that are in both id1 ad id2:

```
In [38]:

data1[(data1.id1.isin(merged_null['id1']) ) & (data1.id2.isin(merged_null['id2']))]
Out[38]:
  id1 id2  number
0   a   z       0
```

Comment: Nice!  Now what if my number_y can have null values going into the merge?  Is there another way of detecting if the join was successful or not?

Comment: The key to this was to detect when the rhs is not present in lhs, in that case you'd still have a column clash so I guess you could filter where all columns matched in values to your filtered merged df, e.g. after `merged_null` step, rename `'number_x'` back to `'number'` drop column `number_y` and you could do a reverse merge: `merged_null.merge(data1, on=['id1','id2','number', how='left') this will ensure now that only the valid rows remain

Comment: Got it, thanks!  I am surprised I have to pass through the data twice but this works.

Comment: @Chris I guess you have to think in terms of arrays of data rather than a db table. Functionality will be similar between dataframes and dbs but not the same so you have to do this to achieve what you want